# Is it possible to quickscope in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In CS 1.6, it was possible to fire accurate shots with the AWP without actually using the scope to sight; this was called quickscoping. It was done by right clicking (opening the scope) and then immediately left clicking to fire. The result was that the game treated your shot as a scoped in shot even though your scope hadn't actually ever appeared, and thus your shot was precise. (Unscoped shots are very erratic.)

I cannot replicate this behavior in CS:GO and did not play CS:Source heavily enough to know if quickscoping functioned there. Does this still ability still exist in CS:GO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No quickscoping like in 1.6 does not work anymore there are a few things that cause this:

1. Zooming in/out takes a lot longer it is no longer instant as in 1.6.
2. If you are moving when zoomed in your accuracy is greatly reduced thus making it 
   impossible to do real quickscopes like in 1.6 seeing you have to stand perfectly still for your shots to go anywhere near your target.

These 2 points make it impossible to quickscope cs 1.6 style.

the quickscoping you can do now is more like quickscoping in call of duty albeit less accurate.

Comment: if you right click and wait a tiny fraction of a second it will be pretty damn accurate. Yes it's not like 1.6 but with a little bit of practice in an empty server it's pretty easy to get the hang of it.

Comment: Agree with @dominicbri7 , you cant negate possibility of Quick Scoping , Yes but its not like it used to in 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Quickscoping is covered in this video at the 1 min 51 second mark:

[CS:GO quickscope and more](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbeNho-9sNY&feature=player_detailpage#t=112s)

And it says it's basically still possible although *not* as accurate as in 1.6.
[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQcx9GwgJvw) seems to confirm that it's still possible to quickscope.

Quoting a post in [this Steam thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2734023):

> Quick scoping and no scoping are perfectly possible in CSGO ...
>    Quickscoping is when you tap mouse2 just before or ~at same time as mouse1 so you are scoping in while shooting...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but neither of those guys understand what a quickscope is in CS terms. You can see their scopes appear numerous times and (of course) the bullets are accurate when that happens. They're using quickscope in the CoD sense which is a completely different thing.

Comment: This post makes me strongly believe they have removed the quickscope method as you describe it: [the art of quickscoping](http://counterstrikego.com/threads/the-art-of-quickscoping.401/)